# A linux interface for my grandma?

Tags: linux, operating-systems

My grandmother can't handle technology, but she wants to be able to communicate with me and my family through the internet. So I thought I could install a Linux in her computer with just the ultra basics. I mean, an interface that I can edit to have only 3/4 buttons. Like telegram, Skype, a recipe site... and that's it. I don't want it to even allow access to anything more complicated, like system configurations and stuff. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are special programs whose purpose is to help older persons to access
computers and the Internet.

One I have heard about is [Eldy Seniors Computer Software for Elderly](http://www.eldy.eu/),
available for most operating systems.

Such a product is much better, in my opinion, then teaching an older person 
about Windows or Linux - they would just get themselves into situations they
would not  know how to get out of, and get frustrated or turned off.

[image]

Comment: I was all set to toss Windows and Linux and jump on this, thinking it was Android-like.  But it looks like basically a desktop and lightweight software suite that runs on the major OSes.  So Grandma would still need to perform OS updates and other basic maintenance.  Still, it looks like a simple UI for everyday stuff.

Comment: @fixer1234: Android is just an interface on top of Linux, and it also needs maintenance, just that a lot of it is automated. The maintenance can be done by yourself whenever required, but Linux does not need updates to just keep on functioning for simple tasks.